# How to GroupBy by result of async Task<string> method and get a grouping by string in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have the below method (it's an extension method but not relevant to this question) and I would like to use `GroupBy` on the results of the method.

```
class MyClass 
{
    public async Task<string> GetRank() 
    {
        return "X";
    }

    public async static Task Test()
    {
       List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass() };
       var grouped = items.GroupBy(async _ => (await _.GetRank()));
    }
}
```

The type of `grouped` is `IGrouping<Task<string>, MyClass>`, however I need to group by the actual awaited result of the async method (string). Despite using await and making the lambda async, I still get `IGrouping<Task<string>, ..>` instead of `IGrouping<string, ...>`

How to use GroupBy and group by a result of async `Task<string>` method and get a grouping by string?

Comment: Check this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/filtering-a-collection-by-an-async-result

Comment: @Fabjan that's a clever way, thank you for sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an asynchronous version of `GroupBy`. It expects a task as the result of `keySelector`, and returns a task that can be awaited:

```
public static async Task<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>[]> GroupByAsync<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TKey>> keySelector)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TSource>> entries = new();
    if (source.TryGetNonEnumeratedCount(out int count)) entries.Capacity = count;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        TKey key = await keySelector(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
        entries.Add(new(key, item));
    }
    return entries.GroupBy(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value).ToArray();
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public async Task<string> GetRank()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return "X";
    }

    public async static Task Test()
    {
        var items = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass(), new MyClass() };
        var grouped = items.GroupByAsync(async _ => (await _.GetRank()));
        foreach (var grouping in await grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Key: {grouping.Key}, Count: {grouping.Count()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Key: X, Count: 2

The `keySelector` is invoked sequentially, for one item at a time. In case you are interested for a concurrent implementation, you could take a look at the [2nd revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56113426/2) of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You probably are looking to `await` all your *tasks* first, then *group*

```
// projection to task 
var tasks = items.Select(y => AsyncMethod(y);

// Await them all
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

// group stuff
var groups = results.GroupBy(x => ...);
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ITlly)

<sub>***Note*** : You didnt really have any testable code so i just plumbed up something similar</sub>

**Update**

the reason why you example isn't working

```
items.GroupBy(async _ => (await _.GetRank()))
```

is because and `async` lambda is really just a method that returns a task, this is why you are getting `IGrouping<Task<string>, MyClass>`

You need to wait for all you tasks to finish first before you can think about doing anything with the results from the task

To further explain what is happening take a look at this [SharpLab example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACg5dgxBWNTbeJAOgBkBLAOwEdCoBmBAJjgGE4BvDLP/hMyQA2bMIA8SGAD44AEQD2AZQUBbAKYAXABY0A5gEEAzgE9qAYwAUNTXEoBKXgJ7onA7AHYEw0gDEATmoASupGAK4ANprWpAAqypr++pb29oTuAL5ucNlMCAAscACyKdzZ7hUAbgCG/nD+1dTAanAAvHDU6gDucEGNzaop6RVwNXWa1UYA1kbtWACi1GEaDQBGEeqkfdR66pYwADRwiDAwjkQjl6RK6hvm0QAebbKKKho6+sZmVg1NaqQAOXUD2ieFSaWyWXQGSAA===)

Your `async` *lambda* basically resolves to this

```
new Func<int, Task<string>>(<>c__DisplayClass1_.<M>b__0)
```

Comment: I suspect too much detail was missing or I am missing something in your reply, but this won't work. I am trying to groupby the result of the method. However after the projection (1st line in your answer) I am losing the actual instances. I edited the question to include better code sample.

Comment: @Marek I dont think you can, you will need to await all the tasks first, then group

Comment: thank you for the clarification, so due to the fact async lambda still returns a task this is syntactically not possible as is. I opted for a different solution. Thank you!